# Updating outputted text in haskeline

Tags: haskell, command-line, haskeline

Haskeline provides the functions `outputStr` and `outputStrLn`, which output to `stdout`, but is there a way to update text that's already been outputted? I'm thinking of, for example, when an installer displays the current percentage installed -- the percentage number updates.

Am I going to need to use a `curses` binding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
delete n = putStr (replicate n '\b')
```

This is (essentially) how QuickCheck does it and it works reasonably well.  I use it in my own code for progress indicators and it gives me good results.  Something more sophisticated will requires a curses binding (or equivalent).

Comment: I was really amused and happy by how simple this solution is, but it's not working for me, either with haskeline or with basic `putStr`

Comment: Oops, I take it back! It only doesn't delete past a newline. Thanks for such a clean solution!

Comment: You might also like `putChar '\r'`.